Pandas read_sql with SQLAlchemy from Oracle Database with many parameters
I have a working setup to read sql data into a pandas dataframe:
connect_string = f"DSN={config.DB};UID={credentials['UID']};PWD={credentials['pwd']};DBQ={config.DB_server};DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=F;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;TABLE={config.table}"
select_string = f"SELECT * FROM {config.table} WHERE Foo LIKE '{config.bar}%'"
connection = pyodbc.connect(connect_string)
data = pd.read_sql(select_string, connection)

but I get the complaint
UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable...
So I tried to use SQLAlchemy with oracledb. But how can I pass the connection parameters? I tried as explained in the docs
cp = oracledb.ConnectParams(dba="W", apa="T", exc="F", fen="T", qto="F", frc=10, fdl=10, lob="T", btd="F", bnf="F", table=config.table)

but this gives the error TypeError: ConnectParams.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dba'

If you have SQLAlchemy 1.4 then read Using python-oracledb 1.0 with SQLAlchemy, Pandas, Django and Flask.  If you have SQLAlchemy 2 then read Using SQLAlchemy 2.0 with python-oracledb for Oracle Database.
Examples for SQLAlchemy 2 are:
engine = create_engine(
    f'oracle+oracledb://:@',
        connect_args={
            "user": username,
            "password": password,
            "host": cp.host,
            "port": cp.port,
            "service_name": cp.service_name
    })

and
engine = create_engine(
    f'oracle+oracledb://:@',
    connect_args={
        "user": un,
        "password": pw,
        "dsn": cs
    })

Use either, depending how your connection string details are available.  You can pass other parameters to the underlying python-oracledb connection command by adding them to the connect_args dictionary.
With the engine created, you can create a dataframe like:
    emp_sql = "select * from emp"
    df_emp = pd.read_sql(emp_sql, engine)
    print(df_emp)


Apparently the parameters are for an access DB. I found a nice SQLAlchemy binding for this and it's working.
